# Disable "The option to save automatically after each result is enabled" warning

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding

Does anybody know a way to disable the message

> The option to save automatically after each result is enabled (NotebookAutoSave->True), but the notebook where you are placing results has not been named. Use the Save command to give the notebook a name, so that it can be saved automatically in the future.

I know what it says, I'm ok with that, and I need the messages window for other things.

It doesn't seem to be an ordinary message which you can `Off`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Edit > Preferences > Messages and set

Minor user interface warnings:

to Ignore.